# jQuery.parseJSON() no Object / not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to access a value from an JsonObject, retrieved via jqXHR.responseText from the backend which is written in Java.

Data returned as Streaming Output by backend:

```
...
String msg = "{'msgkey':'my message to the world'}";
return JSON.defaultJSON().forValue(msg);
...
```

Access via ajax-call, here the done-callback-function:

```
....
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: url,
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {
var resJson = jqXHR.responseText;
console.log("done jqXHR.responseText " + resJson);
var help = jQuery.parseJSON(resJson);
console.log("done help.status: " + help.status);
....
```

Result is: help.status undefined.

Why? Is parsing or the '' wrong? I guess I missed to create an object, but I have no clue why it does not work.

I tried the small example, which is on th jQuery-site, which works perfectly fine:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: pass `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax request... then no need to parse the value your self... also write an error handler to see whether there are any parse errors

Comment: I believe json uses `"` not `'`...

Comment: I have json set as data-type. As for the " and ', I think I tried also this, but will try again.

Comment: Your backend `msg` variable is already a string in almost JSON format (it would be JSON if you used the correct quote character as already mentioned), so what is the `JSON.defaultJSON().forValue(msg)` part supposed to do?

Comment: What does e.g. firebug tell you is coming over the wire?  Have you tried to run it through a json validator (e.g. http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: JSON.defaultJSON().forValue(msg) part supposed to do? -- I do not really know, I thought, creating the Json-Object. Tried to use 'return "{'status':'searched word not found'}" before, but also did not work. About the " and '. I cannot use ' outside of {, this is why I need to use those in the inside. Answer in firebug: "{'status':'searched word not found'}"

Comment: Why do you need this? `data` is already parsed as an object (as long as valid JSON is passed) ?

Comment: I also want to usee it in the fail-callback, there for debugging-messages. Wrong way?

Comment: _"About the " and '. I cannot use ' outside of {, this is why I need to use those in the inside"_ - The JSON format _requires_ double-quotes. I'm sure whatever server-side language you're using has a way to do so, for example in Java it'd be `return "{\"status\":\"searched word not found\"}";`

Comment: @Meru [See my updated Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20831968/1008278) which explains the difference in using dataType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

First get the server to return proper JSON (with double quotes):

```
return "{\"status\":\"searched word not found\"}";
```

Then use the following on the client side:

```
.done(function (data) {
    console.log("data.status: " + data.status);
    ...
```

Since you specify `dataType: 'json'`, jquery will automatically parse the response text into an object, which is the `data` parameter to the `.done()` function.

Comment: Hello! Yes, the escaping I had in before was correct. With escaping the " it works.

Answer (score 1):

set datatype to **`html`** not <s>json</s>

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: url,
  dataType: "html"
}
```

**EDIT**

You have to understand the importance of [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

I will continue to answer your question **"jQuery.parseJSON() not working"**.

- Since you have set  dataType: "json", you are typing to parse json object.
- [jQuery.parseJSON() accepts string ONLY](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/#jQuery-parseJSON-json).
- You cannot parse JSON for second time.
- So directly access values by **"obj.key"**.

  > <s>var help = jQuery.parseJSON(resJson);</s>
  >   console.log("done help.status: " + resJson.status);

**Continuing with you code.**

```
var help = jQuery.parseJSON(resJson);
console.log("done help.status: " + help.status);
```

- you are typing to parse json using jQuery.parseJSON()
- Set data type to "html" or "text"
- Now use `jQuery.parseJSON()`.
- access values by **"obj.key"** as above.

  > **check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/VenomVendor/Def7N/ to see the differences.**
  >   Make sure you open the console before sending request.

Comment: Why? He's expecting a json object, isn't he?

Comment: @Leo He is expecting `json` but question is `jQuery.parseJSON()` is not working, I have updated/improved the answer with demo explaining the difference in dataType

Comment: Yes I expected json. Whereas I am totally ok, if I figure out that an error-message as simple String is better, to transfer only a simple string. So far I am returning from the server following "{\"status\":\"word in\"}". The reason I tried to transfer something that can be parsed to json is, that I thought this would be better. But actually I am not sure at all if it is better maybe I just did it because of the Json hype, so to say that I just was starting to learn to use Json. So if you would have any thoughts on that also, please just share them with me (a she ;) btw).

Comment: @Meru though you expect `json` it's good to use `html` or `text` then create json object(s) using `jQuery.parseJSON()` I have updated the demo with `try catch`. Let me know if have any issues. Happy Coding ;)

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for the try-catch-reminder. So, it there a } too much at the end of the json? So, those try-catch-blocks are highly needed I guess, aren't they? You think json is good then? So I still would need to change the data-format then I apprehend.

Comment: Yes, `Get data >> Validate >> Change >> Rip >> Use` It's also good to use inbuilt functions when you are 100% sure that response JSON is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is already asking for a JSON object:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON
>   is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty
>   response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null
>   or {} instead.

From:
[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

There is no need to parse it further, as it already is a JSON object.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the docu. Yes, it says it. It seams I read but acutally did not read. About the part "response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object", this is that the javascript object is the Json object due to Json objects are javascript object. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it parses the JSON string and returns a Javascript object!